# Curious to know more about set-theoretic functions and their properties in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

I once had this question on a discrete mathematics midterm: If A, B, and C are sets, prove $A^{B\times C} \sim (A^B)^C$, where $X^Y$ denotes the set of functions from $Y$ to $X$. My interest is to know what kinds of functions the bijection from $A^{B\times C}$ to $(A^B)^C$ represents.

Is there a special name or area of study for functions whose inputs are sets of functions, Cartesian products, and sets in general? Are there any notions of continuity, differentiation, integration, etc, for these functions, and how would they be defined?

Comment: Aside: using `\times` in a math environment gives you $\times$.

Comment: Functional analysis is probably what you are thinking of. You need a suitably "nice" function space for any of the structure you allude to in your question. Generally we refer to a mapping between function spaces as an "operator" acting on a given space of functions. For example, the derivative is a linear operator $D:C^{k}(\mathbb{R})\to C^{k-1}(\mathbb{R})$ whose action is given by $f \mapsto f'$. You can also have a "functional derivative" in the variational sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

Comment: Functional integrals also exist, the Weiner integral over the space of sample paths of a stochastic process is a good example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration

Comment: @Hurkyl thank you, this is my first time posting and I appreciate the tip!

Comment: @Wavelet I've read through introductory functional analysis before but the material was more involved with the topology of vector spaces and differential equations. I have yet to find literature that gets into the set theoretic properties of operators between elaborate function spaces like the one I posted, but I will definitely continue my search in functional analysis. I also hadn't heard of the Weiner integral before, it sounds interesting.Thank you!